Was there an update that broke remote desktop?
TLDR; Was there an update that broke remote desktop?
I have similar questions to the post here:
use-logged-in-user-when-connecting-to-ubuntu-using-remote-desktop
I've spent the weekend with my home lab setup trying to get GRD and xrdp going again, it was working a couple weeks ago then stopped after an update.
So fresh installs of 22.04 Desktop on two local private network systems, over and over again. (I tried 24.04, I'll wait for that to mature.)
The combination that works right now for me is GRD with vnc enabled and Remmina vnc connection.
I don't see anything out of the ordinary in the logs.
I'm planning to try other distros to find out if it's Ubuntu or me? Only that's for next month.
In the mean time does anyone know of any issues?
Thanks
P.S. To me it seems "gnome remote desktop" needs one more word at the end so there is no confusion as to what its true intended purpose is, assistance. no?

Do you know if there has been a kernel update since it stopped?
